# Mapping Postgres Array of IDs to Entities

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I have two tables cart and items with schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS item (
  id            SERIAL PRIMARY_KEY,
  name          TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cart (
  id             SERIAL PRIMARY_KEY,
  item_ids       INTEGER[]
);

@Entity(name = "item")
public class ItemEntity {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    private String name;            
}

@Entity(name = "cart")
public class CartEntity {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "item_ids", referencedColumnName = "id")
    List<ItemEntity> items;
}
```

How do I JoinColumn to fetch list of ItemEntity for corresponding item_ids and store in items, the current OneToMany mapping and JoinColumn is not working?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible unfortunately. You might be able to pull off a trick though by using the following mapping:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "(select 1 as dummy, u.item_id from unnest(item_ids) u(item_id))", inverseColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "item_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
@JoinFormula(name = "1", referencedColumnName = "dummy")
List<ItemEntity> items;
```

Note though, that this only works for reading, but not for writing. You should never change the collection in your entity model as Hibernate can't write back to this "join table" with this mapping.

If you also want to support writing to the array, you will have to additionally map the array column as separate field with a special Hibernate array type. If you are using Hibernate 6.1, you can simply use `@Column(name = "item_ids") int[] item_ids;` and Hibernate will take care of the rest, but for older Hibernate versions, you might have to use the [Hibernate types project](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) that provides implementations for such types.